# Route all requests, not matching other routes, to single action

Tags: yii2

I used `catchAll` route to my config

```
'catchAll' => ['site/page']
```

and it works fine.

But all request are going to this action, even that one that have a separate controller/action.

How can I map the routing to match the controller/action at first, and if corresponding controller/action doesn't not exists, then fallback to catch all route?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This config does what you want:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'contact' => 'site/contact',
        '/' => 'page/view',
------> HERE
        '/<url:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>' => 'site/page',
    ],
],
```

You should probably modify the rule to catch more chars. I used this, because I know my routes.

The `catchAll`should be used when you want to put the website into maintenance mode. The error catch can also be used in this case.

Comment: Something like https://harrybailey.com/2012/08/yii-wildcard-catch-all-url-rules/: '<url:(.*)>' => 'controller/action'

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly the intention of the catchAll property:

> When the catchAll property is set, it will replace any route resolved from the incoming requests. With the above configuration, the same site/offline action will be used to handle all incoming requests.

The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to take advantage of the built-in error handling. If you're using the errorHandler like it is defined in the example application, the `site/error` action will be triggered every time an error (such as a non-existing route) is encountered.

In this action, you can use the exception type to handle 404 errors in a specific way, for example:

```
public function actionError()
{
    $exception = Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception;

    if ($exception instanceof \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException) {
        // all non existing controllers+actions will end up here
    } else {
        return $this->render('error', ['exception' => $exception]);
    }
}
```